# Installing django-blog-zinnia

Tags: django, syncdb, zinnia, django-tagging

I am going through the docs of http://django-blog-zinnia.com/documentation/getting-started/install/

and when I syncdb I get this error, tagging is in my installed apps, can someone help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_blog_zinnia-0.12.dev-py2.7.egg/zinnia/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from zinnia.models.entry import Entry
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_blog_zinnia-0.12.dev-py2.7.egg/zinnia/models/entry.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tagging.fields import TagField
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/tagging/fields.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tagging.models import Tag
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/tagging/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tagging.managers import TagManager, TaggedItemManager
  File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/tagging/managers.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import QuerySet, parse_lookup
ImportError: cannot import name parse_lookup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using an old version of django-tagging (your issue is discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/issues/detail?id=141)!) which itself depends on an old version of Django.

Upgrade django-tagging to the latest version; 0.3.1 seems to be the latest release, but the project hasn't seen any activity since 2010 -- I don't know if it's still alive or just very stable.